# How is social media data unstructured data?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, data-mining

I recently began reading up on big data, and how there are tools like hadoop or BigInsights that can manage both structured and unstructured data.

Social Media Analytics is something that can be done on BigInsights, and it takes unstructured data and analyzes/structures it accordingly.

This got me wondering, how is Social Media Data unstructured? For example, the information you can receive on tweets can be called using the Twitter REST API, and returned to you in a structured JSON format.

So isn't Social Media data already structured? If so why do you need a platform that manages mainly unstructured data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some make the distinction „semi-structured”, too.

But the point is the ability to query the data. Yes, Tweets etc. usually have some structure. But it's *not helpful for analysis*.

Given an ugly SQL schema, you could indeed run a query like

```
 SELECT AVG(TweetID) FROM Twitter;
```

but that functionality is useless in practise. And that is probably why the data is best considered unstructured: you do not benefit from squeezing it into a relational schema.

Beware of buzzword bingo with big data, though. More often than not „supports unstructured data” actually means „does not benefit from structure in your data (by using indexes) but rereads data every time”

Answer (score 1):

Its not only about getting the tweets. The real value of the data is knowing about what is being tweeted. Consider Facebook, where we can comment about any picture or a video. We need a platform to know what all the comments are positive about the video or how many are sledging it, or how many comments are real feedback about it. How many are providing suggestions to that to be a better one. And also you need to know how many times the video is shared and liked. Again those who all shared are whom, the one who dislikes it or likes it. Such so many varieties of data can be collected hence these are all called unstructured data.